# MAMP "my website" is not showing on webstart page (default install)

Tags: php, windows, mamp

I want to learn wordpress. Apparently using "MAMP" is a good start.
I have a win 10 Enterprise edition and installed MAMP 5.0.4. (next, next next ... unchecked pro)
I've copied wordpress folder in htdocs
==> Apache green, Mysql green yeey!
Clicking on "open Webstart page" ==> I have only 3 tabs: Start , Tools , MAMP Website.
Can anybody tell me how I can see the "My website" button?

Answer (score 0):

click on tab MAMP on mamp application, click where preferences, input / on my favorite link, click button ok. reload mamp, reload start page .

[image: instruction by images]

Answer (score -2):

ok, I swiched to instantWP. this is working in Firefox after network.security.ports.banned.override ==> 10080

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer. Switching to another tools? Really!? Anyway you can compare them here: https://www.saashub.com/compare-mamp-vs-instantwp